# Modal verbs in Zero Conditionals (Present Real Conditionals)

Tags: modal-verbs, conditional-constructions

What modal verbs can be used in Zero Conditionals (Present Real Conditionals)?
For example, I have stumbled across such examples:

- If you want to go to university, you **must** study hard.
- If it **can** be dreamed, it **can** be done.

So, what modal verbs (from will, would, shall, should, can, could, may, might, must) and in which clauses can we use when forming this kind of conditionals in general?

Comment: I don't think there should be much to explain here. The sentences are meaningful and don't depend necessarily on some grammar rules. Feel free to use any of those, especially in the independent clause; but there is still a lot to cover if you want to use every one of those in dependent clause.

Comment: @AlexTheBN But if i used the "will" in independent clause, for example: "If they want to eat, they *will* go to restaurant", it would be something different than "If they want to eat, they go to restaurant". The former wouldn't be an example of Zero Conditional, it rather would be a First Conditional (Future Real Conditional), and only the latter would be the example of Zero Conditional . So is it really possible to use *any* of the modals even in the independent clause?