# Examples of modal verbs with Zero Conditionals (Present Real Conditionals)

Tags: modal-verbs, conditional-constructions

Yesterday I asked [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/263845/modal-verbs-in-zero-conditionals-present-real-conditionals) question, but haven't got any answer so far... So I try to ask that my question in another way (thorough some simpler questions):

1. Can the following sentences be considered using the Zero Conditional?

- If you get a burn, you might use aloe gel
- If you drink green tea, you may lower your blood sugar
- If you take ginkgo, your memory might improve
- If you take evening primrose oil, you could lower your cholesterol
- If you may take his telephone, you may take his pen as well
- If you should complete some hard task, you should decompose it to a few smaller.

2. Can you provide your own examples in which:

- "Could" is used in dependent clause (if-clause) (I think, that it is
  impossible, because using "could" in dependent clause is in general
  associated with Second Conditional)
- "Should" is used in dependent clause
- "May" is used in dependent clause
- "Might" is used in dependent clause (think it is impossible by the same (mentioned above for "could") reason)

3. And can there exist Zero Conditional sentences with modals *will*, *would*, *shall*? I think, that these modal verbs are "reserved" only for other kinds of conditional sentences, and we cannot use them in Present Real Conditionals.

P.S. I  knew  that terms such "Zero Conditional" are rather vague for native speakers, so to be more precise - I mean conditional sentences, which are used to talk about general truths, facts, habits in present, etc.

Comment: [***You can use modal verbs***](http://www.englishteachermelanie.com/grammar-the-0-zero-conditional/) in Zero Conditional constructions. Both in the if-clause *(If you can’t see the TV, you need glasses)*, and in the result-clause *(You can’t drive a car if you don’t have a license)*. A hard one for me to get my head around is that apparently *If you don’t like your job, quit!* is an example of "imperative with **zero** conditional", whereas *If anyone calls for me, tell them I’m not home!* is "imperative with **first** conditional". But is that really a ***useful*** distinction?

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Yes, I understand, that I can *in principle* use modal verbs in Zero Conditional . My questions are rather about *which exactly modals* I can use and *in which clauses* =) Regarding your example "If anyone calls for me, tell them I’m not home!" - I think, it cannot be unambiguously called first conditional - it's classification is dependent on the context. It can be both used to tell a general rule and to tell what someone should do in particular situation. And depending on the exact meaning it would be able to classify this sentence to one of two types.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica By the way, because of the same reason "If you don’t like your job, quit!" can be called both first conditional sentence and zero conditional sentence (depending on the context) as well

Comment: That's why I only commented. As you obviously realise, most native Anglophones (and indeed most *linguists*, as opposed to most TEFL teachers) don't know or care much about these numbered conditionals. I figured it was be at least *possible* the answer to your question was contained somewhere within my link, but I have to admit that when I got to that "imperative with zero / first conditional" distinction, my eyes glazed over and I decided to just throw the link out here for you or someone else to make sense of it!

Comment: Please note that your last example is not idiomatic. _If you should [verb]_ means _if you happen to [verb],_  and _to decompose_ means _to rot_. I think you mean "If you have to complete some hard task, you should break it down into a few smaller ones".

Comment: @KateBunting, RussoTuristo : The "correct" modal for that last example is *If you **would** complete some hard task, you should decompose it to a few smaller.* Where ***would*** means ***want to...** (have the will / wish to...).* But that usage would be considered "poetic" and/or "dated" by most native speakers today.

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you for your clarification! But can I somehow use *should* in a dependent clause of a Zero Conditional sentence (with meaning *happen to*)? Or when I use *should* there, the conditional sentence becomes some other Conditional? For example, can I say: "If you should visit Moscow, you should be careful at the streets" meaning "If you happen to visit Moscow, you should be careful at the streets"?

Comment: "If you should visit Moscow, you would need to be careful in [or on] the streets."

Comment: @KateBunting And it won't be Zero Conditional anymore?

Comment: If my understanding of the term is correct, I think not.

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you!